# JavaScript regular expression to match X digits only

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers

Can someone help my pea brain figure out why my simple regular expression is not working as I am expecting/wanting it to.

I want to match a date format of MM/DD/YYYY with **exactly** 2 and 4 digits, so something like 01/16/1955.  My code below does that, but it also matches **2+** and **4+** digits, so something like 011/16/1955 or 01/16/19555 (1 extra digit) pass my validation as well.

```
//validate date of birth
var dob_label    = $date_of_birth.find('label').text().slice(0, -1),
dob_mm           = $dob_mm.val(),
dob_dd           = $dob_dd.val(),
dob_yyyy         = $dob_yyyy.val(),     
regex_two_digit  = /^\d{2}$/,
regex_four_digit = /^\d{4}$/;

if ( (regex_two_digit.test(dob_mm)) && (regex_two_digit.test(dob_dd)) && (regex_four_digit.test(dob_yyyy)) ) {
    //a button is enabled here
} else {
    //a validation error is thrown here and the button is disabled
}
```

Comment: Why not have a single input and use date.js to parse and format it to your preferred format... combined with a placeholder works very well...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

need to specify start and end of string

```
/^\d{4}$/
```

Comment: anyways, why not use dropdowns instead?

Comment: I did try that and it doesn't work for me.  No dropdowns because users are keyboard enterers.  The revised code still allows more than 2 or 4 digits.  It does validate digits (I can't do 'aa'), but it still allows too many digits which I can't figure out...*Edit*  wait, it seems to be working but I'm telling you, I tried the beginning/end characters multiple times, wtf???

Comment: lol /shrug...maybe you had some kind of refresh/cache thing going on and the code didn't actually update

Answer (score 1):

try this `^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$`

Comment: When you provide an answer like this, you should also explain why what you're suggesting will work correctly where the code in the question won't.