# How to write a regex (JavaScript) for an id validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

Basically my validation is very simple, but I'm totally new to regex and need this fired up fairly quickly, so here goes: `1234567890` or `123456-7890` it can be, obviously, any number in a range of 0 - 9 and the length must be either 10 or 11 characters.

Can you please show me a way to write a function for this?

Comment: see this stack overflow post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840547/javascript-regular-expression-to-match-x-digits-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isId(id) {
    return /^\d{6}-?\d{4}$/.test(id);
}

isId("1234567890"); // true
isId("123456-7890"); // true
```

Comment: Always welcome @Xeen!

Comment: @Xeen, due note however that you might want to limit \d to [0-9] instead to prevent other number formats. Is it to validate Danish Social Security Numbers?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to post using an iPhone, but, here it goes:

```
/^\d{6}-?\d{4}$/
```

- `^` - starts with
- `$` - ends with
- `\d{6}` - match 6 digits
- `?` - something is optional, in this case `-`
- `\d{4}` - match 4 digits

So, the above would match `123456-7890` and `1234567890`

Answer (score 0):

If the dashes should be possible at any position:

```
function test_id(id) {return /^\d{10,11}$/.test(id.replace(/-/g, ''));}
```

Output:

```
test_id('123')
> false
test_id('2')
> false
test_id('223-345-123-12')
> true
test_id('223-345-12312')
> true
```

Comment: This would be nearly perfect, but a dash can be only after 6th number